# Неверное отображение приложения у разработчика

Tags: java, android, google-play

Я создал приложение. И т.к. это мое первое приложение, я часто выкладывал обновления в закрытом бета-тесте, чтобы видеть ошибки. Так вот, в чем проблема. Сейчас, когда я качаю из Google Play свое приложение на устройство, на котором я тестировал, у меня скачивается неправильная версия. На других устройствах все скачивается правильно. Что делать? Удалять и заново качать пробовал.

Comment: выйти из списка тестировщиков пробовали?

Comment: В таком случае у меня не будет доступа к приложению из Google Play

Comment: @Дмитрий, что именно вы имеете в виду? Если у вас есть закрытый бета тест и версия в маркете, то одни пользователи будет качать релизную версию, а группа тестировщиков последнюю тестовую версию

Comment: есть такая трабла если использовать бд, по крайней мере на моем ванпласе. решается удалением и кеша и данных, потом удалением самой программы и перезагрузкой апарата. и только тогда начинает работать после установки так как надо... но это только на моем устройстве такое, но как вариант можно попробовать.